# how to assign teachers to rooms stored in different tables ?? vb application to assign teachers to exam halls

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a vb application which assigns teachers to exam halls during exams. I want to assign teachers to rooms based on the availability. I have so far been able to take the input of the data as a csv file , store it in an access table and count number of teachers and rooms. But I do not know how to assign teachers to the rooms which I have stored in different tables in a database. how do I go about this? Please help I am stuck.

```
 Private Sub btnTeachersUpload_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTeachersUpload.Click

    ODTeachers.ShowDialog()
    fileNameTeachers = ODTeachers.FileName
    lblTeacherPath.Text = fileNameTeachers

    teacher_Name = readFromCsv(teacher_Name, 0, fileNameTeachers)
    department = readFromCsv(department, 1, fileNameTeachers)
    phoneno = readFromCsv(phoneno, 2, fileNameTeachers)
    email_id = readFromCsv(email_id, 3, fileNameTeachers)
    teachers_availability = readFromCsv(teachers_availability, 4, fileNameTeachers)

    addToDb("teachers", "teacher_name", teacher_Name)
    addToDb("teachers", "department", department)
    addToDb("teachers", "email_id", email_id)
    addToDb("teachers", "phone_number", phoneno)
    addToDb("teachers", "availability", teachers_availability)
End Sub

Private Sub btnTeachersCompute_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTeachersCompute.Click
    connect()
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic
    rs.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic
    rs.Open("select * from teachers where `availability` = 'yes'", cn)
    rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

    no_of_avail_teachers = rs.RecordCount
    txtTeachers.Text = no_of_avail_teachers
    cn.Close()
End Sub

Public Function readFromCsv(arr() As String, ByVal index As Integer, ByVal filename As String)
    Using ioReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(filename)

        ioReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        ioReader.SetDelimiters(",")

        While Not ioReader.EndOfData

            Dim arrCurrentRow As String() = ioReader.ReadFields()

            If arr Is Nothing Then

                ReDim Preserve arr(0)

                arr(0) = arrCurrentRow(index)

            Else

                ReDim Preserve arr(arr.Length)

                arr(arr.Length - 1) = arrCurrentRow(index)
            End If
        End While
    End Using
    Return arr
End Function

Public Sub addToDb(ByVal tablename As String, ByVal fieldname As String, ByVal arr() As String)
    Dim strSql As String
    connect()

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic
    rs.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic
    rs.Open("select * from " & tablename & "", cn)
    rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

    For i = 0 To arr.Length - 1 Step 1
        strSql = "INSERT INTO " & tablename & " (" & fieldname & ") VALUES ('" & arr(i) & "')"
        cn.Execute(strSql)
    Next
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

This is what I have done so far. I have posted a part of it. I am accepting an excel sheet as input and storing it in a database.

I need help with assigning teachers to the rooms. the code is similar for the rooms part of it. Need to assign the available teachers to the available rooms.

My teachers database looks something like this

```
teachers_name    availability
 vagarth             yes
 gaurav              no
 nymisha             yes
```

my rooms database looks something like this

```
rooms            availability
S203                 yes
H405                 no
S304                 yes
```

Comment: I'm afraid you will get less answers and more downvotes if you don't post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am sorry. The code is here now